# HOw to correctly use array_diff()

Tags: php, array-difference

I have the following code:

```
$l1 = file($file1['tmp_name']);// get file 1 contents
$l2 = file($file2['tmp_name']);// get file 2 contents
$l3 = array_diff($l1, $l2);// create diff array
```

Here are the files: 
File 1:

```
6974527983
6974527984
6974527985
```

File 2:

```
6974527983
```

$l3 should be:

```
6974527984
6974527985
```

But, instead it is just spitting out the values from File 1:

```
6974527983
6974527984
6974527985
```

Am I setting this up right?

UPdate -
Using print_r(), I have verified that the files being loaded are being properly parsed into arrays:
File 1 -

```
Array ( [0] => 6974527983 [1] => 6974527984 [2] => 6974527985 ) 1
```

File 2 -

```
Array ( [0] => 6974527983 ) 1
```

So I don't believe there are any issues with the newlines in the text files.

Comment: Seems fine on first glance - I can replicate your expected result on my machine here. Which makes me wonder if something else is going on... are these uploaded files? Food for thought: the result you are getting would happen if the second file was empty, for instance. Maybe there is a problem with the second file?

Comment: Try using FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES as the secnd argument to your `file()` calls

Comment: The files are uploaded. Both files have data in them, so that isn't the issue. I did just try using local files instead of uploading and the results were the same.

Comment: Might seem like a trivial question but why does the digit `1` follow the `print_r()` output in your question update - is it a typo or is that actually appearing in your output?

Comment: Yes, it's actually there. Not sure why. I've usually only seen the 1 when an array is NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the completely useless answer MonkeyZeus. How in the world do you think I knew how to use array_diff() to begin with?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - can we clarify, as Mark Baker recommended above, are you using the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` for each `file()` call? If not, you should definitely try this as this is actually a likely scenario - if the files had differing newline types. I can actually replicate your problem by creating two files with different line endings. Open a terminal and run the `file` command on your text files to get more info on their line endings. And I *can* confirm adding `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` resolves this.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The suggestion by Mark Baker worked. The first time I tried, I tested it wrong. But after the suggestion by Darragh to try again, I saw my error and now it is working. Mark, if you will post this as the answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If each number is on a new line, you could try splitting each file by line breaks and comparing the arrays that way.

```
$l1 = explode("\n", file($file1['tmp_name']));
$l2 = explode("\n", file($file2['tmp_name']));
$l3 = array_diff($l1, $l2);
```

Comment: BTW - file($file_name) Creates an array. I think the code you posted will throw an error.

Comment: Ah my bad - didn't realise it puts it into an array for you

Answer (score 0):

Using the following example you can see that `array_diff()` works as expected:

```
$a = array(
    6974527983,
    6974527984,
    6974527985
);

$b = array(
    6974527983
);

var_dump(array_diff($a, $b));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  int(6974527984)
  [2] =>
  int(6974527985)
}
```

This shows that `file($file2['tmp_name'])` is the problem in your case. Try:

```
var_dump(file($file2['tmp_name']));
```

to check the file's contents.

Comment: Thanks. I just did a similar experiment and found that the results are find. The thing is that I have checked the arrays after the file() calls, and all the data is there.

Comment: I just tryed the var_dump and got : array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } Here is the dump from var_dump(array_diff($l1, $l2)): array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "1 " [1]=> string(3) "2 " [2]=> string(1) "3" } I'm not used to var_dump, but this output seems strange with the 'string(3)' in there.

Comment: `string(3)` because file will **not** remove the line ending. can you delete the comment and add the var_dumps to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will post an answer as I think this will solve your issue.

Without knowing more about the structure of your files, we can only assume that there is a possible issue with line endings. There are three possible line endings:

1. Unix: `\n`
2. Windows: `\r\n`
3. Classic mac: `\r`

I see two possible scenarios here:

1. The line endings in each file are different to each other
2. The line endings in both files are `\r` (classic mac)

As Mark Baker pointed out, you should use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag as the second argument for each of your `file()` calls. This, as far as I can make out from quickly experimenting here, should resolve the issue if one file had Unix and the other had Windows line endings.

However, it does not seem to deal well in cases where at least one file has '\r' line endings. In this case, there's an ini setting that might help:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Consulting the docs for `auto_detect_line_endings`:

> When turned on, PHP will examine the data read by fgets() and file() to see if it is using Unix, MS-Dos or Macintosh line-ending conventions.
>
> This enables PHP to interoperate with Macintosh systems, but defaults to Off, as there is a very small performance penalty when detecting the EOL conventions for the first line, and also because people using carriage-returns as item separators under Unix systems would experience non-backwards-compatible behaviour.

So, TL;DR: debug your line endings to make sure you know what's going on (with `file` or `hexdump` or similar), and use a combination of `auto_detect_line_endings` and `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`.

Hope this helps :)